# Cann't get a Send Filter to work on MassTransit

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, masstransit

I'm trying to capture metadata coming from an HTTP Request (like user-id, trace-id, tenant-id, etc.) and send it through a MassTransit `IRequestClient`.

The client code sending the message is as follows (using HotChocolate to implement a GraphQL API):

```cs
public async Task<Client> ClientCreate(
    [Argument] ClientCreateInput input,
    [Service] IMapper mapper,
    [Service] IRequestClient<ClientCreate> requester,
    [Service] IMessageValidator<ClientCreate> validator,
    CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    var command = await validator.ValidateAsync(
        mapper.Map<ClientCreate>(input), cancellationToken);
    
    var response = await requester.GetResponse<ClientContract, ErrorResponse>(
        command, cancellationToken);

    return response.TransformResponseMessage(mapper.Map<Client>);
}
```

In order to do that, I created the following filter:

```cs
public class SendApiDomainMetadataFilter : IFilter<SendContext>
{
    public void Probe(ProbeContext context)
    {
        context.CreateFilterScope(nameof(SendApiDomainMetadataFilter));
    }

    public async Task Send(SendContext context, IPipe<SendContext> next)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Sending metadata ...");
        if (context.TryGetPayload(out IServiceProvider? serviceProvider) &&
            serviceProvider!.GetService<IResolverContext>() is { } resolverContext &&
            resolverContext.GetDomainMetadata() is {} metadata)
        {
            var serializedMetadata = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(metadata);
            Console.WriteLine("Sending metadata: '{0}'", serializedMetadata);
            context.Headers.Set(nameof(DomainMetadata), serializedMetadata);
        }

        await next.Send(context);
    }
}
```

The problem is that the filter is never called. I tried the following setup:

```cs
builder.Services.AddMassTransit(bus =>
{
    bus.UsingRabbitMq((context, configurator) =>
    {
        // ...

        configurator.UseConsumeFilter(typeof(ValidateConsumeFilter<>), context);
        configurator.UseSendFilter(typeof(SendApiDomainMetadataFilter), context);

        configurator.ConfigureSend(sendConfigurator =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Configuring send pipeline");
            sendConfigurator.UseFilter(new SendApiDomainMetadataFilter());
        });

        configurator.ConfigureEndpoints(context);

        configurator.Host(...);
    });
});
```

I guess that only one of `configurator.UseSendFilter` and `sendConfigurator.UseFilter` should be necessary to call send on the filter, but none are being useful for that.

What am I missing from this configuration to make every call of `IRequestClient.Send` to go through `SendApiDomainMetadataFilter.Send` before sending the message to `RabbitMQ`?

**UPDATE**: Indeed, I previously tried to create a [Scoped Filter](https://masstransit-project.com/advanced/middleware/scoped.html) like the one I have for `ValidateConsumeFilter`. All the examples work on the Consume side. The issue is that if I send a message from outside a consumer/saga, the Send pipeline is not being used. After Chris suggestions, I created a simple DummySendFilter:

```cs
public class DummySendFilter<TMessage> : IFilter<SendContext<TMessage>>
    where TMessage : class
{
    public void Probe(ProbeContext context)
    {
        context.CreateFilterScope("DummySendFilter");
    }

    public async Task Send(SendContext<TMessage> context, IPipe<SendContext<TMessage>> next)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Dummy Sending " + typeof(TMessage).Name);
        await next.Send(context);
    }
}
```

And because I have two services communicating through MassTransit (gateway and service), I added the dummy filter in both, like:

```cs
// Inside UsingRabbitMq
configurator.UseSendFilter(typeof(DummySendFilter<>), svp);
```

When I send the message from the gateway using the interface `IRequestClient<ClientCreate>`, the message is send without going through the dummy filter. Then It gets to the consummer, after going through the validation filter (as expected), and then, when the consumer responds, that response message goes through the dummy filter (configured on the service, not on the gateway), printing `Dummy Sending ClientContract`, (as expected).

I just don't know how to activate the send filter from the gateway, even before it gets to RabbitMQ

**UPDATE**: Using a filter on `PublishContext` worked as suggested by the answer. Thanks Chris for pointing to the right direction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scoped filters should be generic, just like your consume filter. And you can more easily get your filter dependency from the constructor as a scoped filter instead of all that workaround stuff being done to "get domain metadata."

Since you have a scoped consume filter, you should already understand what you need to create the send filter properly.

UPDATE: It's likely because your request is *published*, and not *sent*. So create a matched set of send/publish filters to have either scenario.

Comment: Thanks Chris, love your YouTube series, and for the quick answer! I'll add some updates to the question, because I tried the same you are suggesting, but it didn't worked.

Comment: As updated in my question, the issue is that the send filter is being used when sending a response back to the gateway, but it is NOT used when calling `IRequestClient`'s `GetResponse` from the gateway, in the first place. I need to "intercept" the message created in the gateway, before it gets into the queue, to add the corresponding headers to the context, but the interception is not happening there.

Comment: Updated answer to include details about publish vs send.